# It is possible to simulate inside of a sun netra T5220?

Tags: solaris, simulate, sun

I want to know if it is possible simulate a SO inside of a T5220. 
Because two servers are needed with different specific software that works on a T5220, but there is only one T5220 physically with one hard disk and the software works on solaris 10.

I am new in this kind of themes, but simulate this kind of platform in an x86 architecture is possible? Because there are servers of this kind available for this use.

I am seeking for all kind of options.
The software also is compatible with the next platforms: SunFire V440, Netra T2000, Netra 440 and Sun Fire X4270 M2. Any of those can be simulated? and if it is possible, what do i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create both multiple logical domains and multiple zones on a T5220.

With logical domains (Oracle VM for SPARC), you simulate different physical machines, each one with its own Operating System.

With zones, you have OS level virtualization including the ability to simulate older Solaris releases with S9 and S8 branded zones.

On the other hand, I'm not aware of any usable and current Solaris on SPARC emulation layer available for x86.